# Stack around the variable 'fname' was corrupted

Tags: c++, fopen

the program is to read back multiple bin files
there is an above-mentioned error happened at the end of "main" program. where did I code wrong? thank you for help

```
    char* read_back(const char* filename) 
    {
    FILE* pFile;
    long lSize;
    char* buffer;

    pFile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (pFile == NULL) { fputs("File error", stderr); exit(1); }
    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(pFile);
    rewind(pFile); // set file pos at the begining
    // copy the file into the buffer:
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
    size_t result = fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);
    if (result != lSize) { fputs("Reading error", stderr); exit(3); }
    fclose(pFile);
    return buffer;
    }
int main() {
    const char *fname[2] ;
    fname[0] = "C:\\0_data.bin";
    fname[1] = "C:\\1_data.bin";
    fname[2] = "C:\\2_data.bin";
    int i;
    char * readback_data;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
    { 
        readback_data=read_back(fname[i]);      
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const char *fname[2] ;
```

This declares an array with two values, two pointers: `fname[0]` and `fname[1]`.

```
fname[0] = "C:\\0_data.bin";
fname[1] = "C:\\1_data.bin";
fname[2] = "C:\\2_data.bin";
```

This attempts to put three pointers into an array that's sized only for two. That's your stack corruption, right here.